# Удаление символов из текста в java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как удалить символы из текста за исключением русского/английского алфавита, знаков пунктуации и пробельных символов с помощью регулярных выражений? Есть ли готовый класс (в терминах regexp)? Хотелось бы избежать прямого перечисления.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
replaceAll("[[\W[0-9_]]&&[\S]&&[^А-Яа-я-.?!)(,:]]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

В [regex-паттерне](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) есть предопределенные группы символов:

> Predefined character classes
>
> .    - Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
>
> \d    - A digit: [0-9]
>
> \D    - A non-digit: [^0-9]
>
> \s    - A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
>
> \S    - A non-whitespace character: [^\s]
>
> \w    - A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
>
> \W    - A non-word character: [^\w]

К сожалению, нет готовой группы символов, чтобы убрать из строки всё, кроме букв, цифр и знаков препинания.
Поэтому нужно комбинировать.

Например так:

```
String str = "1 my example str ~ !";
System.out.println("before:" + str);
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\w ,.:\"'!\\t]", "");
System.out.println(" after:" + str);
```

Comment: К сожалению, ваш вариант не учитывает русские символы.

Comment: Если что, вот удобный онлайн тестер регулярок: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html